# How to filter by Manager Property from a Users request

Tags: graph, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I want to find my subordinates using Graph API. I tried to filter the Manager property. But that is an User Object. So I am unable to pass filter parameter. Event I am unable to expand the Manager Property.

The query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id&$expand=manager does not return any information about manager. I have tried the same with beta version, but no luck.

Is there any way to filter users by Manager or to get my Subordinates? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` endpoint, in particular *`expand` and `select` query options could not be combined together*. Refer [Query parameter limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#query-parameter-limitations) article which mentions similar issue

There is a *workaround* which allows to retrieve user details along with manager property using the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?select=*,manager&expand=manager
```